# Order statistics for non independent variables

Tags: order-statistics

I have three random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3$ where $X_1$ is from distribution $F_1$.

$X_2=X_3$ are from distribution $F_2$ and they happen to be identical.

My question is what will be the order statistics for these three variables? I am aware of the Bapat-Beg Theorem, which deals with non-identical but independent distributions. But the problem here is that my $X_2, X_3$ are not independent.

My first guess is that I can regard this as a situation with only variables $X_1,X_2$. But my concern is that when $X_2=X_3$ is larger than $X_1$, $X_1$ will be the third highest value while when we only consider $X_1,X_2$,  $X_1$ can not be the third highest value. So it does not seem right to simplify this scenario to variables $X_1,X_2$ only.

EDIT: I try to derive from the definition of order statistics. $\mathbb{P}(X_{(1)}\leq x)=1-\mathbb{P}(X_1\geq x, X_2\geq x, X_3\geq x)=1-\mathbb{P}(X_1\geq x, X_2\geq x)$ since we assume $X_2=X_3$.

$\mathbb{P}(X_{(2)}\leq x)= \mathbb{P}(X_1\leq x, X_2\leq x, X_3\leq x)+ \mathbb{P}( X_1>x, X_2\leq x, X_3\leq x)$
$=\mathbb{P}(X_{(3)}\leq x)+ \mathbb{P}(X_2\leq x\leq X_1)$

And $\mathbb{P}(X_{(3)}\leq x)=\mathbb{P}(X_1\leq x, X_2\leq x, X_3\leq x)= \mathbb{P}(X_1\leq x, X_2\leq x)$ by $X_2=X_3$.

And $1-\mathbb{P}(X_1\geq x, X_2\geq x), \mathbb{P}(X_1\leq x, X_2\leq x)$ are just expressions for order statistics when there are two variables for comparison.

Is the argument above correct?

Comment: If $Y=Z$, then $\min(X,Y,Z)=\min(X,Y)$, $\max(X,Y,Z)=\max(X,Y)$, and $\text{median}(X,Y,Z)=Y$, so indeed you can reduce all three order statistics to two variables.

Comment: Do you know how to express the order statistics for the variables? I think Bapat-Beg Theorem does not apply in this case?

Comment: I do know, but that would be asking about the distributions for $\max$ and $\min$, and that would belong in a different question (which might well have been asked and answered already).

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(X_{(1)}\leq x)=1-\mathbb{P}(X_1\geq x, X_2\geq x, X_3\geq x)=1-\mathbb{P}(X_1\geq x, X_2\geq x)$ since we assume $X_2=X_3$.

And $\mathbb{P}(X_{(2)}\leq x)=\mathbb{P}(X_{(3)}\leq x)=\mathbb{P}(X_1\leq x, X_2\leq x, X_3\leq x)= \mathbb{P}(X_1\leq x, X_2\leq x)$ by $X_2=X_3$.

And $1-\mathbb{P}(X_1\geq x, X_2\geq x), \mathbb{P}(X_1\leq x, X_2\leq x)$ are just expressions for order statistics when there are two variables for comparison.

~\\
Is the argument above correct?

Comment: If you omitted $P(X_{(2)}\le x)=$ then the argument would look correct…but because $X_2=X_3$ the distribution for that second order statistic has a special form.

Comment: I think $\mathbb{P}(X_{(2)}\leq x)= \mathbb{P}(X_1\leq x, X_2\leq x, X_3\leq x)+ \mathbb{P}( X_1>x, X_2\leq x, X_3\leq x)$
$=\mathbb{P}(X_{(3)}\leq x)+ \mathbb{P}(X_2\leq x\leq X_1)$.

Comment: Actually, if I use this expression and the Bapat-Beg Theorem to compute out my expressions, it turns out the 2nd order statistics is just the distribution of $X_2$. Is this your expression?

Comment: That is correct.